# how to create a highcharts area with the top area highlighted?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Area in highcharts highlights the bottom area by default.

[image: highcharts default area (bottom area is highlighted]

I want to highlight the top area.

[image: My Expectation]

**Is there a recommended way to do that?**

Based on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/area-threshold/), I can change the threshold to 250 to get similar result (as shown in *My Expectation*)

The only solution I can come up with is:

1. find out the max y of all data points.
2. let `MAX = k * y_max`. (`k` is a custom-defined factor, say, 1.2; to get better result, `y_min` is also needed to get a proper `k` dynamically)
3. Use the following configuration.

```
yAxis: {
   max: MAX 
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        threshold: MAX 
    }
}
```

**But this requires some js computation and I wonder if highcharts supports this itself.**

---

UPDATE:

I think I'd better state my original question here. I want to support 3 types of areas:

1. Within Upperbound and Lowerbound
2. Below lower bound
3. Above upper bound

I implemented the first one with arearange. But arearange doesn't support missing upper/lower bound; it will remove the thresholds altogether if one bound is missing.

**Is there a way to avoid computing the `threshold` setting by myself?**

Comment: The solution you proposed looks elegant - I'd suggest the same thing.

Comment: How come the downvote without comment?

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS you can obtain something similar to your picture:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        color: '#ff0000',
        fillColor: '#ffffff',
        fillOpacity: 1
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-plot-background {
  fill:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

or almost identical using `threshold` together with `negativeColor`:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        color: "#FF0000",
        fillColor: '#f00000',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        threshold: 300,
        negativeColor: '#f00000',
        negativeFillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container2" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/0sameLb6/

Comment: I can't use css solution because there might be multiple areas. Let me have a try on negative color.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. If I want to take the 3 cases into consideration, I have to use arearange for case 1 and area for case 2 & 3? Just wonder if there is a better solution. It's painful that highcharts doesn't support partial threshold. http://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/o8wmzw0a/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TorsteinHonsi.

I posted a [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8139), and @TorsteinHonsi responded quickly and commited a [change](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/f1684358ba0f175d28d9233188c1178764563c29). `area` will support `-Infinity/Infinity` shortly.

Comment: This does not seem to work with zones